# Placing a div overlaying flexslider disables the direction controls

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, flexslider

I’m trying to place a div with a logo inside it, overlaying flexslider.

Playing with css attributes, as position (absolute and relative), and z-index, I achieved what I want… But, the problem now is that the controls (side arrows), are un-clickable, nothing happens when you click it, since the logo div is over the slider…

I guess that adjusting z-index parameters will solve the problem, but I’m not able to get it work…

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could try changing the z-index of the slider controls, but you might need to post some code so someone here can help. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: You were right Iharby, I fix the problem adjusting carefully the z-index values. Many thanks!